# Saving an Image after applying an Aforge.NET filter

Tags: c#, image, save, gdi+, aforge

I have the following snippet which loads an image from memory, resizes it, and attempts to save the resized image.  I get the "A generic error occurred in GDI+" error on the resizedImage.Save(), but I can't see where an image/bitmap is being held on to.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    using (var m = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)))
                {
                    using (var n = new Bitmap(m))
                    {
                        using (var newImage = n.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, n.Width, n.Height), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
                        {
                            var filter = new ResizeBicubic(200, 200);
                            var resizedImage = filter.Apply(newImage);

                            resizedImage.Save(searchImage);
                            resizedImage.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure that bitmap `n` has `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`?

Comment: Yes, the picture format is correct I verified it just now.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the filename `searchImage` if look at the doc of [Bitmap.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx) in MSDN there is no specific exceptions (`IOException`) for problems with path.

Comment: searchImage path looks good and the directory exists

Comment: have you ever found a solution for this? it looks like i've the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have not.  If you do, please keep me informed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save the image at the same origin file. Try to change the output file. AForge keeps the origin file Open.